# Within Qualtrics, how I stop a background hover color from bleeding from the descriptive area to the item area?

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, qualtrics

Firstly, I'd like to apologize if the wording in this questions is awkward as I'm not exactly sure how to write this clearly. In a nutshell, I wanted to do two things:

- Program a tooltip with a table into the question area of Qualtrics (which is completed)
- Have the background of every row change color when a person hovers.

Now I have "completed" that last part BUT the background color is bleeding into the item response area and I cannot tell how to stop it. I have been racking my brain and I'm assuming that its something simple that I'm overlooking. The code I have been using is included below. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Javascript (in the header under Look & Feel):

```
.myExpandItem
{
text-decoration: underline;
position: relative;
}

.myExpandItem:hover .myExpandBox {
display: block;
}

.myExpandBox
{
position: absolute;
background: white;
opacity: 1;
border: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
border-radius: 15px;
min-height: 200px;
min-width: 450px;
display: none;
left: 300px;
top: -375px;
padding: 10px;
color: black;
font-size: 12.000000pt; 
font-family: 'Arial';
}
```

And here's the associated HTML code within the body:

```
<span style="font-size:16px;"><span style="font-
family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">To remind yourself of the 
description for each area, hover over the link named BLAH below.
</span></span>&nbsp;<div><br>

<span class="myExpandItem"><div align="right">BLAH</div><span 
class="myExpandBox">

<style type="text/css">

table {
overflow: hidden;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
padding: 10px;
position: relative;
outline: 3;
}

tbody tr:hover {
background-color: lightblue;
}

</style>


<table style="background: white;border-radius:15px;-moz-border-
radius:15px;-webkit-border-radius:15px;">

<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="col"><h4>Area</h4></th>
    <th class="col"><h4>Description</h4></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<thead>
    <tr>
         <td colspan="2"><hr></td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>ITEM 1</td>
    <td>DEFINITION.
</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>ITEM 2</td>
    <td>DEFINITION.
 </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>ITEM 3</td>
    <td>DEFINITION.</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody><tbody>

 </tbody></table>

 </span> 
 </span>
```

As you can see, the light blue "bleeds" over when hovering over the item response area. Again, thank you for your help ahead of time. I appreciate it.

Comment: Qualtrics uses tables to layout a lot of their pages. Have you tried using a special id on this table and utilizing that to select ONLY this table?

Comment: Thanks Anthony. It didn't work initially but it set me on the right path by eliminating the table itself as the problem. I changed how the hover populated (answer area) and now it works! Also your tag actually helped with another section of this piece which wasn't in my original post. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I amended the markup and now it works. Again, there is no doubt a MUCH MORE elegant way to do this so any comments are greatly appreciated. Regardless, I hope this helps others.

```
<span class="myExpandItem"><div align="right">BLAH</div><span 
class="myExpandBox">

<style style="text/css">

.hoverTable{
    width:100%; 
    border-collapse:collapse; 
}

 .hoverTable td{ 
      padding:7px;
 }

 .hoverTable tr{
      background: white;
 }

 .hoverTable tr:hover {
      background-color: lightblue;
 }

.hoverTable tr:first-child:hover {
      background-color: white;
 }

.hoverTable td:first-child:hover {
      background-color: white;
 }


table#t01 {
      overflow: hidden;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      background-color: white;
      border-radius:15px;
      -moz-border-radius:15px;
      -webkit-border-radius:15px;
}

</style>


<table id="t01"; class = "hoverTable">

    <tr:first-child>
        <th class="col"><h4>Area</h4></th>
        <th class="col"><h4>Description</h4></th>
    </tr>

    <td:first-child>
         <td colspan="2"><hr></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>ITEM 1</td>
        <td>DEFINITION.</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>ITEM 2</td>
        <td>DEFINITION.</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>ITEM 3</td>
        <td>DEFINITION.</td>
    </tr>

</table>

</span> 
</span>
```